# Only one single span works

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code provide a dot effect, like a loading bar(" Loading., Loading.., Loading...), but the problem , that only one single span id works, the second one wont, i dont know why...
please help me out guys

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function showProgressDots(numberOfDots) {

    var progress = document.getElementById('progressDots');

    switch(numberOfDots) {
        case 1:
            progress.innerHTML = '.';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(2)',200);
            break;
        case 2:
            progress.innerHTML = '..';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(3)',200);
            break;
        case 3:
            progress.innerHTML = '...';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(1)',200);
            break;
    }
}
window.setTimeout('showProgressDots(1)',100);
//-->
</SCRIPT>

Loading<span id="progressDots" style="position:absolute;"></span>
SecondLoading<span id="progressDots" style="position:absolute;"></span>
```

Comment: ID should be unique.. you cannot have same ID for more than 1 element.

Comment: So there no way to have one, that can be used multiplay times?

Comment: @Vega I think we need to write this sentence near the SO logo.

Comment: @VisioN True.. I wish I could create a macro for this and the delegated events.

Comment: Here is a [little plugin (*with options*)](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gh5CD/1/) just for you :)

Comment: thanks! does it work cross browser??

Comment: Gaby aka G. Petrioli, can you make that plugin start like : Loading, loading., loading.., loading... and start over Loading, loading. etc, instead of Loading., loading.., Loading... ? and can you please make auto timmer to clear after 1 second ?

Comment: @user1417815, added it as answer including the corrections you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting a little plugin i made for this (*for the fun of it..*).

```
(function($){
    $.fn['progress'] = function(_options){
        var options = {
            symbol: '.',
            delay: 200,
            length: 3,
            duration: 0
        };
        if (typeof _options === 'object'){
            $.extend(options, _options);
        } else if (_options === 'clear'){
            return this.each(function(){
                clear.apply(this);
            });
        }
        
        function display(){
            var self = $(this),
                txt = self.text() + options.symbol;
            if (txt.length  > options.length){
                txt = '';
            }
            self.text( txt );
        }
        
        function clear(){
            var self = $(this),
                timer = self.data('progressTimer');
            
            clearInterval(timer);
            self.text('');
            self.removeData('progressTimer');
        }
        
        return this.each(function(){
            var self = $(this),
                that = this,
                timer = null;
            
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                display.apply(that);
            }, options.delay);
            
            self.data('progressTimer', timer);
            
            if (options.duration){
                setTimeout(function(){
                        clear.apply(that);
                    }, options.duration);
            }
        });
    }
                         
})(jQuery);
```

You use it with

```
// to set it
$('some-selector').progress({/*options*/});

// to stop it
$('some-selector').progress('clear');
```

with available *`options`* being

- `symbol` the character to add on each iterations (*default is `.`*)
- `length` the max number of symbols to display before it starts over (*default is 3*)
- `delay` the time it takes for each extra symbol to be added (*in milliseconds*) (*default is 200*)
- `duration` total duration (*in milliseconds*) before clearing the plugin (*default is 0 which means no auto clearing*)

[example <sup>points to jsfiddle</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gh5CD/1/)

```
$('some-selector').progress({
  symbol: '*',
  length: 10,
  delay: 100,
  duration: 5000 
});
```

---

***update for comment***

To clear it automatically after some specific time just add a timeout to your code..

so

```
var progressElements = $('some-selector').progress({/*options*/}); // set the progress
setTimeout(function(){
   progressElements.progress('clear');
 }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
```

---

***update for 2nd comment***

changed the plugin code above to allow for a `duration` parameter.

If specified, it declares the time after which the plugin will automatically clear..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gh5CD/3/ (*the second loader will clear after 2 seconds*)

Comment: but this Print: Loading., Loading.. , Loading... and start again with a dot : Loading. instead of starting with empty dot like: Loading, Loading. , Loading.. , Loading... etc..

Comment: the code in the answer is correct, the live example is the old one.. see it here with the new code http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gh5CD/2/

Comment: Works great, but could you implant the auto clear every 1 second please also

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli could you please implant the auto clear? i want to accept this

Comment: @user1417815, added an extra option to say how long it should work ... by default it does not stop but if you give it the option `duration:1000` it will clear after a second..

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli instead of add a new: .progressDots:eq(0), .progressDots:eq(1), .progressDots:eq(2) everytime i need to use it more places, can you marge it into one, that can be used as many times i want???

Comment: @user1417815, i did it that way to show that you can have different options at the same time... just use `.progressDots` as the selector and all will be the same..

Answer (score 6):

Here is the short solution if you need.

*HTML:*

```
Loading<span id="progressDots1"></span>
SecondLoading<span id="progressDots2"></span>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function loading(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id),
        i = 0,
        dots = "...";

    setInterval(function() {
        el.innerHTML = dots.substring(0, ++i);
        if (i % 3 == 0) i = 0;
    }, 500);
}

loading("progressDots1");
loading("progressDots2");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dzFL3/

Comment: thank you for removing that code string begin passed to `setInterval` - was going to work over it, but got stuck with another question...

Comment: that code dont work: <script type='text/javascript'>

function loading(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id),
        i = 0,
        dots = "...";
    
    setInterval(function() {
        el.innerHTML = dots.substring(0, ++i);
        if (i % 3 == 0) i = 0;
    }, 500);
}

loading("progressDots1");
loading("progressDots2"); 

</script>


  <div>
    Loading<span id="progressDots1"></span>
</div>

<div>
    SecondLoading<span id="progressDots2"></span>
</div>

Comment: @user1417815 Put the `script` tag with JavaScript code after the actual `div` tags with loading content. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzFL3/1/.

Comment: @VisioN Just wanted  to brag -> Check my DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/3/ << Feel free to comment.

Comment: @Vega Your effort and the breathtaking code definitely desire acceptance :D Who needs that petty laconism... :)

Comment: @VisioN haha.. tbh.. i wanted to see if i made a blunder anywhere.. but I felt good after doing some plain javascript code (no jQuery)

Comment: @Vega Yes, so am I. Especially if the solution comes fast and elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 1:** Wrote a customizable loader so you can register/un-register loaders.. See below,

**Edit 2:** As Vision pointed out

> Just out of interest... I thought, what is the point to create multiple timers and store them in the array? If you wait for some time, the separate timers will desynchronize. How about this: jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/5

**Improved Code:** (From Vision's [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/5) and use of `getElementsByTagName`)

```
var timer = null,
    dotLimit = 3,
    elements = [];

function registerProgressDots(progress) {
    for (var i = 0; i < progress.length; i++) {
        elements.push(progress[i]);
    }

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            with(elements[i]) {
                innerHTML = innerHTML.length == dotLimit ? '' : innerHTML + '.';
            }
        }
    }, 200);
}

function unRegisterProgressDots(index, clearDots) {
    if (typeof index == 'undefined' || index == null) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        elements.splice(index, 1);
        if (elements.length == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    if (clearDots) {
        var progress = document.getElementsByClassName('progressDots');
        for (var i = 0; i < progress.length; i++) {
            progress[i].innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
}

window.setTimeout(function() {
    var spanTags = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    var progress = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < spanTags.length; i++) {
        if (spanTags[i].className.indexOf('progressDots') >= 0) {
            progress.push(spanTags[i]);
        }
    }

    registerProgressDots(progress);
}, 100);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    unRegisterProgressDots(null, true);
}, 10000); //stop loading text after 10 seconds
```

[**Final DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/6/)

Comment: And what if `numberOfDots` is `3`?

Comment: @user1417815 You got to explain us what you are trying to achieve.. I am not sure what you are trying to do here... Read the Note in the post

Comment: That whole switch can be replaced with `numberOfDots % 3 + 1`

Comment: he want to animate dots like in loading text by appearing 1 and 2 after that 3 points and looping this action

Comment: maybe this is similar [solution](http://blog.lucadioli.com/animated-loading-text-with-javascript-and-jquery/)

Comment: @user1417815 Should work in all modern browsers.. If not `document.getElementsByClassName('progressDots')` should be changed to `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` and parse each span for class `progressDots`

Comment: @Vega how do you parse each span for class progressDots ? explain please

Comment: Just out of interest... I thought, what is the point to create multiple timers and store them in the array? If you wait for some time, the separate timers will desynchronize. How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/5/?

Comment: @VisioN True.. created separate timers.. so you can unregister each of them separately.. probably I should have allowed him a way to register 1 by 1 too.

Comment: Yes, but you can unregister each of the elements just moving it out of the interval array. I tested it works fine.

Comment: @VisioN  cant you implant document.getElementsByTagName('span') inside your solution, to see how that done?

Comment: @user1417815 Here is the complete version for you http://jsfiddle.net/rMpK9/6/ <<-- Added improvements from Vision and the `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Thanks guys, true help.. i would wish that i could accept both help, sad they only allowed only one..

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for the improvement and it is definitely a better way to do.. See that's the reason I wanted to brag so you get to see what you missed :)

Comment: @user1417815 Here is the version with `getElementsByTagName`: http://jsfiddle.net/dzFL3/2/. You can use this if you like.

Comment: @Vega No problem :) We are here to help each other!

Comment: The end of the code: window.setTimeout(function() {    
   unRegisterProgressDots(null, true);
}, 10000); /  gives me problem in internet explore 8

Comment: Please help me fix last line of code to work without errore in internet explore 8, i want to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

```
Loading<span id="progressDots" style="position:absolute;"></span> //element before script

<script type="text/javascript">
var i='', dots=20;

showProgressDots();    
function showProgressDots() {
    var progress = document.getElementById('progressDots');
        progress.innerHTML = i;
    i+='.';
    if (i.length<dots) setTimeout(showProgressDots, 200);
}
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vFmw8/)